# Choose Representation for Avro Schema Logical Type in Java

Tags: java, avro, instant

I have this Avro schema

```
{
  "name": "SimpleEvent",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The compiled JAVA class uses `java.time.Instant` to populate the timestamp field. I want to populate it with `org.joda.time.Instant` for different reasons.

I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Is it possible? And how?

Using:

- Maven, avro-maven-plugin v1.11.0
- Apache Avro v1.11.3
- Java 11